# How to see the code executed in my trigger or any other apex class using green & red lines

Tags: apex, force.com

I want to see the code executed in my trigger or any other apex class called from the trigger using green & red lines after insertion of records of that object in the org. This should look similar to the code coverage which we see for a class using green & red lines after we execute test classes in developer console. I want to see the code executed or the code coverage after I insert a record in the org instead of a test class. Is there any tool available ? or can I see it through any API call or something ? Any Idea is much appreciated.
Thnx

Comment: I don't know tool for this. You can check if specific lines in you code are executed by setting _checkpoints_ in developer console. Then if you see checkpoint in the **checkpoint** tab then this line was executed.

Comment: @Edelrabe I think the problem with checkpoints is that we can not set more than 5 checkpoints in a class. Although adding checkpoints in a large class is very difficult task and it is difficult task to see checkpoints also. Is there any API available or some library where I can see the lines of code executed ? because If I get that then I can easily create green and red lines accordingly .

Comment: No, I don't think so, since it runs in the cloud we cannot trace or live debug the code.

Comment: The only way would be to add debug statements and look at the debug or system log afterward to see which lines executed or their associated values that would tell you if they executed to determine which lines were executed.

Comment: @crmprogdev yeah I know debug logs but that is again a pain to add them in a large class to see the flow.